# Python just straight up making no sense

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

Guys python is just straight-up wrong. Here is my code:

```
#Repeat until loop
count = 0
while (count < 9):
  print("What is your name?")
#If creator code 
 x = input("Type Stop program or enter your name ")
  if x == "QiwiCode":
      print("")
      print("Good morning creator")
      print("")
#Quit code 
 elif x == "Stop program" or "stop program" or "stop Program" or "Stop Program":
      print("Quitting.")
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Quitting..")
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Quitting...")
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Goodbye")
      count = 10
#Name if not creater or quit code
elif x != "Stop program" or "stop program" or "stop Program" or "Stop Program" or "QiwiCode":
      print("")
      printdHello",x,)
      print("")
```

I put in a random name (tom) and it just ran the quit function! Can someone help?

Comment: `elif x == "Stop program" or "stop program"` That is not the right way to check for multiple values.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: tip - If you ever find yourself saying that "x is wrong" where x is an established, 30 yrs old, widely used language - it is more likely that **you** did something wrong

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, especially if it is some basic facet of the language, like an if-else statement

Comment: Anyway, python's syntax is often pretty close to natural language English, but it's important to remember it isn't a natural language, it's a programming language. The "or" doesn't distribute like that, so in english, "the ball is red or green or blue" means the same as "the ball is red or the ball is green or the ball is blue" but python doesn't work like that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elif`'s can be improved a little bit.

change : `elif x == "Stop program" or "stop program" or "stop Program" or "Stop Program":`

to : `elif x == "Stop program" or x == "stop program" or x == "stop Program"...`

Noticed the `x` I added?
Try to add it to the other elif and it might work.

EDIT:
This will solve your problem and will work (Probably). But as John Gordon pointed out. You could force `x` to lowercase, then doing something like

`elif x.lower() == "stop program":`

Then it doesn't matter if it's "Stop Program", "stoP Program" or "sToP PRogRaM",
it will work for all of them.

Comment: In this specific case, a better option is to force `x` to lowercase so you only need to check against one value: `if x.lower() == "stop program"`

Comment: Good point. Added that to the answer

Comment: "can be improved a little bit" more of an issue of being made correct rather than improving

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: That's all well and good, but now the Good morning creator part is not working...

Comment: Actually fixed it. Removed x.lower() on the hello creator part and replaced it with x. works just fine, thanks for your help.